# Filter nested of nested in Mongoose Populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have an object that looks like this: (that is the output of **Mongoose** query)

```
let systems = [
    {
        "maxUserLevel": 1,
        "subsystems": [
            {
                "sections": [],
                "name": "apple"
            },
            {
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "name": "banana"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "sun",
            },
            {
                "sections": [],
                "name": "orange"
            }
        ],
        "systemID": "12345"
    },
    {
        "maxUserLevel": 3,
        "subsystems": [
            {
                "sections": [],
                "name": "blue"
            },
            {
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "name": "pink"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "red",
            },
        ],
        "systemID": "15654"
    }];
```

The Mongoose query:

```
this.model.System.find({username: user.username}, {
    _id: 0,
    allowedOrganizations: 0,
    name: 0,
    updatedAt: 0,
    createdAt: 0,
    versionKey: 0
})
    .populate(
        {
            path: "subsystems",
            populate: {
                path: "sections",
                select: "name -_id",
                match: {
                    allowedUsers: user.id
                }
            },
            select: "name metadata -_id",
        }
    )
    .exec((error, systems) => {
        return res.status(200).json({
            data: systems,
            success: true
        });
    });
```

I'm looking for a way to removes the `subsystems` that do not have `sections`.
After hours of searching I think there's no way to filter `populate` based on nested `populate`, so I tried with some ways like this:

```
if (systems.subsystems.length > 0) {
    let test = [];
    systems.subsystems.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (value.sections.length !== 0) {
            test[index] = value;
        }
        if (systems.subsystems.length === index + 1) {
            return test;
        }
    })
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm not sure this is the best way**, but it solved my problem:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

systems.forEach((value, index) => {
    systems[index].subsystems = _.filter(value.subsystems,
        item => !item.sections.length == 0
    );

    if (systems.length === index + 1) {
        return systems;
    }
});
```

It removes all `subsystems` that do not have `sections`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate query with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "maxUserLevel": 1,
      "subsystems": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$subsystems",
          "as": "s",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              "$$s.sections",
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8qVjufWEjFo)

Also your query should contains a `$match` stage (like your `find` stage) and `$lookup`.